# How to detect that my Android App was closed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

I'm trying to detect when my app was opened, put on foreground, put on background and closed.

I tried to do it like this:

```
ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(ApplicationLifecycleTracker())

...

class ApplicationLifecycleTracker: LifecycleObserver {
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun onMoveToForeground() {
        Timber.d("APP CONTROL - RESUMED")
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun onMoveToBackground() {
        Timber.d("APP CONTROL - PAUSED")
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
    fun onAppOpened() {
        Timber.d("APP CONTROL - OPENED")
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun onAppClosed() {
        Timber.d("APP CONTROL - CLOSED")
    }
}
```

So far, I can get these events right: `ON_CREATE`, `ON_START` and `ON_STOP`.

But `ON_DESTROY` is never called when I close my application.

How can I get the callback for `ON_DESTROY` correctly?

Comment: Probably you application is still in the "recent apps" try removing it from there and it should fire. Or open many other appy so that you get into a memory-pressure scenatio where the system closes apps that are not in foreground. see also https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Actually your activity is not finished completely. System is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space.

check with function  **isFinishing()** for track the correct status of activity

more details refer [onDestroy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onDestroy())